# Example of two simple function approximations of a measurable function whose integrals converge to different limits.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. We know that if $f$ is a **bounded** measurable function **supported on a set of finite measure**. Then, if $\{\phi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ are two different sequences of simple functions (linear combination of characteristic functions) approximating f, we have, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X \phi_n=  \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X \psi_n $$.

I am unable to construct an example where the function $f$ is either not bounded or not supported on a set of finite measures and two different sequences of approximating functions  $\{\phi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ such that $\{\phi_n\}\rightarrow f$, $\{\psi_n\}\rightarrow f$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X \phi_n\neq \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X \psi_n $$.

Comment: Maybe it is a silly comment but notice that those assumption are used to certainly make sense to the integrals $\int_X$.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment those assumptions are there to make sure that everything is well defined.

Take for example of $f$ being the bounded (step) function that bounces from $-1$ to $1$ over all $\mathbb{R}$ and any two step functions that approximates $f$.

If $X$ would be bounded there would be no problem and the theorem holds. But as $X$ becomes to be $\mathbb{R}$, then the problem is that the integrals over $X$ are no more well defined and the theorem does not make any sense.